# Ruby on Rails time zone issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, timezone

I am working with a legacy Rails 2.3.11 incident reporting application and I'm having some issues with the time zone. For some reason when a user selects a date/time from a datepicker it seems to store the value fine (I check the database and the value is correct), but when the value is retrieved from the database it is 5 hours in the future. Does anyone know why this might be?

I have checked the time on both the app server and the database server and they seem to be correct: `Mon Jun 10 07:52:18 CDT 2013`

Here are some values that might be important:

**environment.rb**

```
  config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
  config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
  config.active_record.time_zone_aware_attributes = false
```

**incident.rb (model class)**

```
  def self.format_time(time)
    if (time)
      time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p")
    else
      return "Not Available"
    end
  end

  def self.time_format
    "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p"
  end
```

Edit: Also note that I cannot replicate this issue on my local development machine. It seems to only be an issue when the app is pushed to the server.

Comment: what timezone is the server using ?

Comment: When I run the `date` command it says CDT. Specifically it says `Mon Jun 10 07:52:18 CDT 2013`.